# How can I make the height of each subplot consistent in matplotlib.pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following program generates six subplots. But the height of each subplot is inconsistent. How can I make the height of each subplot consistent?

```py
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
a=np.random.random((100*100*3))
b=np.random.random((100,100,3))

ax1=plt.subplot2grid((2,4),(0,0),colspan=1,rowspan=1)
ax1.axis('off')
ax1.imshow(b)
ax2=plt.subplot2grid((2,4),(0,1),colspan=2)
ax2.hist(a,bins=30,range=(0,1))
ax3=plt.subplot2grid((2,4),(0,3),colspan=1)
ax3.axis('off')
ax3.imshow(b)

ax4=plt.subplot2grid((2,4),(1,0),colspan=1,rowspan=1)
ax4.imshow(b)
ax4.axis('off')
ax5=plt.subplot2grid((2,4),(1,1),colspan=2)
ax5.hist(a,bins=30,range=(0,1))
ax6=plt.subplot2grid((2,4),(1,3),colspan=1)
ax6.axis('off')
ax6.imshow(b)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: "But the height of each subplot is consistent. How can I make the height of each subplot consistent" reread that sentance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subplots can be manipulated at the end by changing their locations and sizes. Here is the relevant code that is added before `plt.show()`.

```
...
#... some code above
plt.figure(figsize=(10,4))
#... some code here
...

# manipulate some subplots
p2 = ax2.get_position()
p3 = ax3.get_position()
newpx = [p2.x0, p3.y0, p2.width, p3.height]

# set location and size of `ax2` subplot
ax2.set_position(newpx, which='both')

p5 = ax5.get_position()
p6 = ax6.get_position()
newpx = [p5.x0, p6.y0, p5.width, p6.height]

# set location and size of `ax5` subplot
ax5.set_position(newpx, which='both')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The result:

[image: 2x3subplots]

Answer (score 0):

If you use `add_subplot()` instead of `subplot2grid()`, all graphs will be of the same size. Why should `subplor2grid()` be used?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
a=np.random.random((100*100*3))
b=np.random.random((100,100,3))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2, 3, 1)
ax1.axis('off')
ax1.imshow(b)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2, 3, 2)
ax2.hist(a,bins=30,range=(0,1))

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(2, 3, 3)
ax3.axis('off')
ax3.imshow(b)

ax4 = fig.add_subplot(2, 3, 4)
ax4.imshow(b)
ax4.axis('off')

ax5 = fig.add_subplot(2, 3, 5)
ax5.hist(a,bins=30,range=(0,1))

ax6 = fig.add_subplot(2, 3, 6)
ax6.axis('off')
ax6.imshow(b)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Because I want to double the length of the second and fourth subplots while keeping the height unchanged. What should I do?

Comment: Is it to double the height of the second and fifth blue graphs otherwise?